# Overloading and Java types concepts

Tags: java, oop, types, casting, overloading

```
public class Class2 extends Class1{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class2 c2 = new Class2();

        c2.m3(10);
        c2.m3(10.5f);
        c2.m3('a');
        c2.m3(10l);
        c2.m3(10.5);
    }

    public void m2() {
        System.out.println("M1 method of class2");
    }

    public void m3(int i) {
        System.out.println("int argument");
    }

    public void m3(float j) {
        System.out.println("float argument");
    }
}
```

Getting error when trying to call  c2.m3(10.5); Could you please assist why this is happening?

Comment: *"getting error"* what error do you get?

Comment: The method m3(int) in the type Class2 is not applicable for the arguments (double)

Comment: Can you show `Class1` too if you have any methods there

Comment: Well your solution is right ahead of you, directly in the error description. 10.5 is a double. The method wants a float.

Comment: try `c2.m3(10.5f);`

Comment: Also it has nothing to do with Overloading.

Comment: by default floating point / decimal numbers are trested as double in java. thus you need to use c2.m3(10.5f); for the call. Also, If we direct assign char variable to int, it will return ASCII value of given character.

Comment: this is true they are also accepting char(c2.m3('a')) and long (c2.m3(10l))

Comment: @nitinghogare that's simply because you can widen a char and a long to a float without loss of information. But you can't do the same by narrowing double -> float.

Comment: actually i wanted to learn about automatic promotion in java. Can anyone help me in undestanding it?

Comment: Ask another question in that case please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's refer to the language spec [§5.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3) Invocation Contexts:

> Loose invocation contexts allow a more permissive set of conversions,
>   because they are only used for a particular invocation if no
>   applicable declaration can be found using strict invocation contexts.
>   Loose invocation contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>
> - an identity conversion (§5.1.1)
> - a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2)
> - a widening reference conversion (§5.1.5)
> - a boxing conversion (§5.1.7) optionally followed by widening reference conversion
> - an unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) optionally followed by a widening primitive conversion

Basically, when you call a method, the arguments you give can only undergo one of the conversions described above.

> If the type of the expression cannot be converted to the type of the
>   parameter by a conversion permitted in a loose invocation context,
>   then a compile-time error occurs.

You are trying to convert from a `double` (`10.5` is a `double` literal) to a `float`, which is a narrowing primitive conversion, which is not permitted in an invocation context.

`10` works as an argument because an identity conversion (from `int` to `int`) is allowed.

`10.5f` works because it is a `float` literal and an identity conversion (from `float` to `float`) is allowed.

`'a'` works because this is a primitive widening conversion (from `char` to `int`), which is allowed.

`10l` works because this is also a widening primitive conversion (from `long` to `float`).

For more information on the kinds of conversions, see [§5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1).

Comment: got the answer. Thanks all and @sweeper

Comment: @NitQA If you think the answers helped you, please consider accepting the answer you found most helpful by clicking on that checkmark!

Answer (score 2):

> Getting error when trying to call c2.m3(10.5); Could you please assist why this is happening?

What's happening here is that you are passing a `double` to the `m3()` method, when you call `m3(10.5`), while you only have two `m3()` methods that accepts either an `int` or a `float`, so that's where your problem come from.

Just change your last line like this:

```
c2.m3((float) 10.5);
```

You need to cast the `double` value to a `float` or pass a float like `10.5f`.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the method with the wrong type: It seems you intended to invoke this overload: `void m3(float j)`; but that cannot be called with `10.5`. The literal `10.5` is a `double`, and there's no method overload taking a `double` parameter.

You should change the call to `c2.m3(10.5f)` or add yet another overload with the signature `void m3(double j)`

Comment: One could also use a cast, which could lead to precision loss though

Comment: For reference: [§3.10.2 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2) defines that all `float` literals must be suffixed with `f`, otherwise they are `double` literals.